# How to input condition in yii find()?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, find, conditional-statements

I have two tables `Account` and `User`.

`Account` table contains `account_id`, `username`, `password`

while `User` table contains `user_id`, `account_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`.

What I want is for `yii` to display the contents of the `user` table of the one logged in so I used this code

```
$user= Yii::app()->user->id; //to get the account_id of user logged in
$userModel = User::model()->find(array('condition'=>'account_id' == $user));
//to find data in the user table with the account_id similar to the
//account_id of the one logged in
print_r($userModel); //to check if I got the correct data
```

but for some reason, no matter who logs in, the `print_r($userModel)` is returning data with the `account_id == 1`

please help :/

Comment: How do you know that which user is logged in by database( means by which field)?

Comment: This probably does not do what you intended: `array('condition'=>'account_id' == $user)`; Did you mean `array('condition'=>"account_id == $user")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Yii 1 you can try with findByAttribute

```
$userModel = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('account_id'=>$user));
```